# unbound not forwarding query to another recursive DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, unbound

I'm trying to use unbound to forward DNS queries to other recursive DNS server. My **unbound.conf** looks like:

```
forward-zone:
name: "."
forward-addr:x.x.x.x
forward-addr:x.x.x.x
forward-addr:x.x.x.x
```

But when I use the command

```
#  unbound-control lookup google.com
The following name servers are used for lookup of google.com.
forwarding request:
Delegation with 0 names, of which 0 can be examined to query further addresses.
It provides 3 IP addresses.
x.x.x.x not in infra cache.
x.x.x.x not in infra cache.
x.x.x.x not in infra cache.
```

How to make unbound forward the DNS query to another recursive server that is defined in forward zone?

Comment: `A forward-zone entry with name  "."  and  a  for-ward-addr  target will forward all queries to that other server (unless it can answer from the cache).` Did you make sure that the cache was empty?

Answer (score 2):

**`unbound-control lookup` isn't the command it appears to be:** From your output, it shows you *are* forwarding to the listed addresses, despite appearing to be a negative response (unless it is *actually* printing 'x.x.x.x'!)

Breaking it down:

- `forwarding request:` well, this is key.
- `Delegation with 0 names ...` is reporting that none of the forwarders were configured with a domain name using `forward-host` *(versus `forward-addr`)* which need to be resolved first.
- `It provides 3 IP Addresses ...` the following addresses are the configured forwarders.
- `x.x.x.x not in infra cache.` (i.e, *host* cache) stores network stats about the upstream host so the best resolver can be chosen later for queries. This will be empty until the host is actually used for a lookup; it also will expire relatively quickly. If you do a `dig google.com @127.0.0.1` and run `lookup` again, you should see the cache updated.

If you were configured as a *recursive* resolver and *not a forwarder*, this command would instead show you the nameserver records and host statistics (infra) that would be *used for* a recursive lookup, without actually doing that lookup.